# The shortest path to an array of struct

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, struct, c11

In order to get an array of struct I did:

```
int main() {
    typedef struct {
        int size;
        double time;
    } timming_s;
    timming_s timming[5];
    timming[0] = (timming_s){(int)1e5, 0.0};
    timming[1] = (timming_s){(int)2e5, 0.0};
}
```

Is there a more compact form to get it? I was trying to write:

```
int main() {
    struct timming_s {
        int size;
        double time;
    } timming[5];
    timming[0] = {(int)1e5, 0.0};
    timming[1] = {(int)2e5, 0.0};
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the initializer list be the other way around? `1e5` is a double, `0` is an int. Or in case the order is correct, you should add some casts.

Comment: Question  edited. The order was correct. But I missed the fact `1e5` is a double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main(void) {
  struct {
    int size;
    double time;
  } timming[5] = {{1e5, 0}, {2e5, 0}};
//  } timming[5] = {{.size = 1e5, .time = 0}, {.size = 2e5, .time = 0}};
}
```

Comment: How to proceed in case `typed` becomes needed?

Comment: @KcFnMi You can't `typedef` don't allow to declare variable in the same time like struct does. http://rextester.com/JOLNL9436